# How to use blame in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, svn, phpstorm, webstorm

Is it possible to use `svn blame` in WebStorm?

Comment: right click in gutter, annotate maybe...., that is cvs equiv though.

Comment: @AdamForbis Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.1/viewing-changes-information.html, Using annotations.
The **Annotate** command is available from Subversion nodes of the Version Control menu, the context menu of the Editor left gutter, file context menus, and the file history view

Answer (score 2):

1. Enable git in VCS.
2. In the VCS menu, select Git and then Annotate.